# Returning JSON from WCF after POST in Android

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf

I just started coding for my android application and I am unsure of how I should start coding.

If I want to do lets say a login in my android application. How should i start?
Is it possible if I do it in this way:

> Send POST to my WebService > Web Service Validates credentials > Return user information

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your process is correct.

If you have simple needs like what you describe using the default serializer should be enough, just specify:

```
WebMessageFormat.Json
```

Later if you need a full fledged JSON library use **[Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)**

A small tutorial to get you started (it uses a similar use-case): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec

Do not forget to use authentication over **HTTPS** only...

Comment: So following the tutorial, if I just write a read JSON code on my android side, it should work right? Also is POST used to just send something over and GET is used to send and return a value?

Comment: Technically you can use both but POST is preferred for security, because GET parameters are more easily exposed, like in servers logs.